# sympy's ConditionSet object not iterable

Tags: python, set, sympy

I would like to generate a simple set based on a condition to mimic set builder notation, and then enumerate its contents. I tried the following based on an example [in the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html):

```
from sympy import Symbol, S, ConditionSet
from sympy.abc import x

new_set = ConditionSet(x, x<7, S.Naturals)
iterable = iter(new_set)
print("done")
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    iterable = iter(new_set)
TypeError: 'ConditionSet' object is not iterable
```

Why is it that I cannot enumerate the `ConditionSet` object? It has finite contents so I would assume this should be possible?

Comment: What if you change `x<7` with `x>7`? It is not finite anymore.

Comment: I guess not, but you can apparently still enumerate infinite sets like naturals as well. The following, for instance, works with no errors: `iter(S.Naturals)`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'ConditionSet' object has no attribute '__iter__'`.  `S.Naturals` does have this method, which you can examine (it's a simple generator).  To `iter` an object it either has to be a sequence (e.g. `list`) or define this method.

Answer (score 0):

ConditionSet does not try hard to resolve its expression with an infinite base set. For linear or quadratic univariate inequalities, it wouldn't be hard to do so at instantiation, however. But for now you have to do so on your own:

```
>>> c = ConditionSet(x, x < 7, S.Naturals)
>>> solveset(c.args[1], c.args[0], domain=S.Reals).intersection(c.args[-1])
Range(1, 7, 1)
```

The Range is iterable.

```
>>> next(iter(_))
1
```

(In theory you should be able to set `domain=c.args[-1]` but the solver does not handle such sets well, yet.)